# Function call after app termination in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I call a function after the app termination?

I have to download few details from server even if app is terminated and then send a notification to user. How do I do this?

Comment: You can't guarantee any code will run if your app is terminated. In particular if the app is killed from the app switcher

Answer (score 4):

The only way to download data when your app is not running (not in the foreground, not running in the background) is to use [Background Fetch](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/).

It will work if:

- The app has been killed by the system (for memory purpose for example)
- The device restarted and the app hasn't been killed by the user before

Note that this will not work if:

- The app has never been started after being downloaded
- The user manually killed the app (through the multi-tasking screen)

Comment: NSUrlsession is not working in background fetch. How do i do this?

Comment: I have to download the data from server. It is neither going to the success block nor the failure block.